# c# Winform best way to update form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to update a selected record using this code when closing the form:

```
interestsTableAdapter.Update(newCityCollectionDataSet);
```

The record is NOT updating doing this.  I use the same code to update datagridviews but I do it while it is validating.  Is there a better way to do this with FORMS as opposed to controls?

Comment: Can you show us the code - what have you tried, have you debugged it etc?

Comment: Why do you want to update the *form* when closing it?  Makes no sense.

Comment: I just need the fields on the form updated.  What would you suggest if I do not do it when the form closes?  I am not a fan of using buttons to save.

Comment: private void frmInterests_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            interestsTableAdapter.Update(newCityCollectionDataSet);
        }

Comment: voting to close this question as its not a real question and unable to determine what is actually being said!

Comment: @korrowan You need to provide more code- the line you're using to save isn't enough. When is this code being called? In an OnFormClosing override of your `Form`-derived class? In a handler of your form's `FormClosing` event? You need to provide more details. Also, the tags for this question might not be relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this isn't working could depend on when you're trying to save your record. There's a big difference between executing code *before* your form's closing and ***while*** your form's closing.

Typically, failures *while* the form's closing (in handlers of a Form's FormClosed event) are caused by the application exiting before the handler gets a chance to do its job.

On the other hand, handlers of a Form's FormClosing event are invoked ***before*** the form even starts to close, and can even keep it from closing. These handlers are almost always waited for, as long as the form is the application's "main" or "startup" form (and not a child of it).

Without seeing more code than what you've provided, I'm afraid it's all I can do to advise you to execute your code before the form closes (via its FormClosing event), rather than while it's closing (via its FormClosed event).